# Why does my LD_LIBRARY_PATH get an uninstalled terminal launch?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

In general, what I do to get the result:

I drive a team:
    `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib`

Checking:
    `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Result:     `/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib`

When I restart or open the new terminal my `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is disabled.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables are available only in the shell where you have created them. If you want to set an environment variable permanently then you can do it either by adding it to the .bashrc file in your home directory. Or by adding it to the /etc/environment file. In case of .bashrc it will be available only for your user, and it will be available only for newly opened shells. In case of /etc/environment it will be available for all newly logged-in users (logout/login needed) and you must have root privileges to do it. Do not write export into these files, just add  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/lib` at the end of them.